# How do I connect and make request to flickr,facebook and other social media?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, flickr, picasa

I am trying to integrate flickr,facebook and picasa in my webpage so that User can authenticate by signing into his account from any one of these and he can get images from his account and upload onto my webpage.And after editng those images he can upload back to the same website.

So how should I proceed.Can anyone give me your suggestions?
Here is the sample link what I mean?

http://www.showzey.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the API documentation

- Flickr: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/
- Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/
- Picasa:
  http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html